# Find-and-replace optimization

Tags: javascript, array

I'm looking for some JavaScript code improvement and optimization. Is it possible to optimize this block of code (for example, remove double array loop)?

```
replace: function(ex, str) {
    var arr = str.match(/{add_([A-Z]+)}/gi);
    if (arr && arr.length) {
       arr.each(function(e){            
          var id = e.replace('{add_','').replace('}',''),
          o = Core.get_data_by_id(ex.extensions, id);   

          if (o && o.status =="1") {
            str = str.replace('{add_'+id+'}', o.html);
          } 
       });
    } 

    var arr2 = str.match(/{banner_([0-9]+)}/gi);
    if (arr2 && arr2.length) {
       arr2.each(function(e){
         var id = e.replace('{banner_','').replace('}',''),
         b = Core.get_data_by_id(ex.banners, id);

         if (b && b.status =="1" && b.code && b.code.length) {
            var content = '<div class="units-row banner_'+b.id+'"><ul>' +
            b.code.each(function(s){
               content += '<li>'+s.code+'</li>';
            });                     
            content += '</ul></div>';
            str = str.replace('{banner_'+id+'}', content);
         } 
       });
    }

    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a function as the second argument. Example:

```
str = str.replace(/{add_([A-Z]+)}/gi, function(match, id) {
  var o = Core.get_data_by_id(ex.extensions, id);   
  return (o && o.status == "1") ? o.html : match;
}); 

str = str.replace(/{banner_([0-9]+)}/gi, function(match, id){
  var b = Core.get_data_by_id(ex.banners, id);

  if (b && b.status =="1" && b.code && b.code.length) {
    var content = '<div class="units-row banner_'+b.id+'"><ul>' +
    b.code.each(function(s){
       content += '<li>'+s.code+'</li>';
    });                     
    content += '</ul></div>';
    return content;
  } 
  return match; 
});
```

EDIT: I've added the second part.

Comment: But I will have two regular expressions: /{add_([A-Z]+)}/gi and /{banner_([0-9]+)}/gi

Comment: That was just an example. Your second regular expression is independent from the first one and can be replaced in a similar manner.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how to combine 2 regular expressions and pass it to replace function?

Comment: I wouldn't do that. The functions a different enough to leave them separate, so leave the regular expressions separate, too.